# BipartiteMatching hangs with floating-point weights in Mathematica 7 (package Combinatorica)

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to use Combinatorica's BipartiteMatching algorithm on a weighted graph. I need to use real numbers as weights.
If I try the following

```
graph = CompleteGraph[1, 1]
graph = SetEdgeWeights[graph, {1}]
BipartiteMatching[graph]
```

it correctly gives the perfect matching {{1,2}}.

But if instead I try this

```
graph = CompleteGraph[1, 1]
graph = SetEdgeWeights[graph, {1.}]
BipartiteMatching[graph]
```

(the only difference being the decimal point), it hangs, apparently forever.
Am I missing something obvious?
Any help would be much appreciated!